# How to deploy a .NET web application in Mono hosted on a Linux Server?

Tags: asp.net, linux, vb.net, mono

We have a web application we've been writing in VB.NET. We want to get that running within a Linux server, specifically CentOS. I installed Mono version 4.0.1 on the server, as well as xsp and mod_mono. I'm not sure however, how to properly configure the setup to get the application running. We have several .aspx and .dll files. Do I just FTP them over to the server? I think we would need some wrapper executable script to get the application going, since all the websites I have been looking at state that, but I'm not sure how that works for a web application.

Comment: What are you using to develop?

Comment: Hey, so we are using Visual Studio 2010. I tried to FTP but I'm getting the following error:

'Unable to open the Web site 'ftp://<IP address>:<port>/<directory>'. Rebex  FTP/SSL does not support SFTP/SSH protocol. Use Rebex SFTP or SSH component instead'. I found a Rebex download here (https://www.rebex.net/ssh-pack/download.aspx), but it's only for a 30-day free trial. Is there any other utility I could use to FTP my files to a SSH server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Visual Studio**, you should use FTP to deploy your asp.net applications into GNU Linux environment. The IDE would take care of what files has to be deployed in order to get your asp.net application working.

But if you are using **MonoDevelop** you could use **SSH Fuse**. Here you have a *Getting Started* guide about working and deploying ASP.NET apps from MonoDevelop to an Linux environment:

http://www.monodevelop.com/documentation/creating-aspnet-projects/

If you don't have experience with FUSE, don't worry I get this for you

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh

---

**That's all.** You don't need a wrapper as you mentioned before, it is pretty much like and an standard IIS site. Quite easy right? It has to work always that your application and its dependencies are compatible with mono, and indeed with apache or xsp configured correctly. 
Cheers!